# How do I create custom calendars beyond what is offered out of the box?

Tags: calendar, web-part, list-view

I have searched and searched for resouces on this for SharePoint 2010 and I am unable to find anything.

I want a much more robost calender and I know c#, but I don't know where to begin.

Please help! Where should I look? Does anyone have any material on this? Has anyone coded one up from scratch before?

Comment: No offence, but how do you expect to get any reasonable answers without listing some of the things that you would like it to do? Robust and Beyond don't give much of a clue.

Answer (score 1):

2 Questions:

What do you want it to do?

and

How are you going to use it?

I ask, because it might be cheaper for your project to splash out on a third party product (such as from Bamboo (http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-calendar-plus-web-part.aspx) or elsewhere). I can guarantee you it'd take more than 2 days to build one, which is approximately the cost of a server licence for the Bamboo example.